# Jquery after method() and html document

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to use Jquery's after() method to add content dynamically to a page and appear in the webpage source.

I'm able to use the after() method but after the content is loaded and I check the websites source the div that was added trough the after() does not show.

Comment: How do you check the source? How about firebug/chrome dev tools?

Comment: please provide example code of your problem

Comment: Are you using internet explorer? If you check the source code in chrome or firefox the div will be there. IE sux. But take care, anything that does read your page without javascript enabled will not see the source code changes (like the google crawler).

Answer (score 1):

No.  "View Source" in most browsers shows you the body that was downloaded to the client by the request (you could see something similar using a tool like `wget`).  This does not execute scripts at all.

If you want to see source that is generated some browsers have "View Generated Source" that stringifies the current DOM tree back into HTML for you to view.  Firefox also has its own developer tools and the very popular firebug, and Chrome Inspector is another helpful development tool.  You can use "Inspect Element," usually in the context menu, to see the stringifies DOM as well.